# Minimize and restore windows using the shortcut key

Tags: c#, wpf, window, restore, minimum

I used the shortcut to minimize the window, but I don't know how to restore it.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.F1:
                    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                break;
            case Key.F2:
                    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will need low level windows keyboard hook or global hotkey, however it does raise the issue, what if you are in another application that uses the keyboard shotcut as well.

Comment: @TheGeneral I tagged wpf, not Winform. I raised the question of how to do wpf, not the question of how to do winform. But I found a way to do wpf on a website.

Comment: There is no difference, neither wpf or winforms will have access to keyboard events when its minimised. thats why you need to hook

Comment: @TheGeneral I am well aware of that. However, winform says it supports handlers, but wpf does not. It took me time in that part.

Comment: I dont have the time to help you at this moment, ill remove the duplicates

Comment: @TheGeneral But thanks to your duplicates, I've got my bearings. Thank you.